# Regex YouTube channel link

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a Javascript regex which is able to extract the channel identifier of a YouTube channel link. I've found some solutions on Stackoverflow but I'm still missing a solution which is also capable to work with the YouTube channel alias (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/@youtubecreators)

So the regex should be able to match following URLs:

1. https://www.youtube.com/c/coca-cola --> coca-cola
2. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCosXctaTYxN4YPIvI5Fpcrw --> UCosXctaTYxN4YPIvI5Fpcrw
3. https://www.youtube.com/@coca-cola --> coca-cola
4. https://www.youtube.com/coca-cola --> coca-cola

The matching should also work even when there's a path attached like https://www.youtube.com/@Coca-Cola/about

Any hints are welomce!

Comment: Are these really the only YouTube URLs you want to match?  There are mobile URLs as well.

Comment: Hello Tim, just looking for YouTube channel URLs. Just checked on Android an it's the alias version. Don't know whether this is different on Apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you're looking for is:

```
https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/(?:c\/|channel\/|@)?([^/]+)(?:\/.*)?
```

```js
const urls = [
  "https://www.youtube.com/c/coca-cola",
  "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCosXctaTYxN4YPIvI5Fpcrw",
  "https://www.youtube.com/@coca-cola",
  "https://www.youtube.com/coca-cola",
  "https://www.youtube.com/@Coca-Cola/about",
]

const pattern = /https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/(?:c\/|channel\/|@)?([^/]+)(?:\/.*)?/

for (url of urls) {
  console.log(url.match(pattern)[1])
}
```

Comment: How would I need to adjust the regex to also allow "https://m.youtube.com"?

Comment: Use `https:\/\/(?:www|m)\.youtube\.com\/(?:c\/|channel\/|@)?([^/]+)(?:\/.*)?`